# Get locale specific value of selected product option by attributeText

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, localisation, ce-1.9.2.2

I have a product attribute for delivery time `akeneo_delivery_time`, that's filled from a PIM (akeneo) by import. This is of type "Dropdown" with scope of "Store View" (We have two storeViews, with locales of de_DE and fr_FR). The options contain translations of the delivery time text for every locale.

I wanted to keep the `delivery_time` attribute that comes with magento (mage_setup), which is of type "text", in order to not break compatibility which 3rd party extensions.

My idea was to write an indexer that transferes the attribute frontend-values of the "Dropdown" to the text attribute "delivery_time". There is no problem with that, it works fine.

But i cannot get the locale specific value. `getAttributeText` gives my the correct option for the storeViews, but not in the locale of that storeView. I get the option text in "de", never in "fr".

```
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

        $resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product');
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $akeneoDeliveryTime = $product->getAttributeText('akeneo_delivery_time');
            $product->setData('delivery_time', $akeneoDeliveryTime);
            $resource->saveAttribute($product, 'delivery_time');
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here? Do I need to set locale somewhere?

---

I have seen in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes, it works like this:

```
   public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
{
    $data = array();
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

But here "$product" contains translates option values from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

with this

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                   ->setStoreId($store->getId())
                   ->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('akeneo_delivery_time');
```

Comment: like this, i get no values from "getAttributeText" at all.

Comment: I've updated the code. Give it an other try.

Comment: ok, this get´s me back to the previous state. I get the correct option, but in the wrong locale. always 'de", although the locale of the second storeView is 'fr".

Comment: any update on this issue?